# NOT JSON ERROR when opening a .ipynb file converted from .txt

Tags: python, json, ipython

I have a .txt file which looks like this:

```
1
{
2
"cells": [
3
{
4
"cell_type": "markdown",
5
"metadata": {},
6
"source": [
7
"## 1. Test and filter outliers"
```

I removed all the line numbers and still got the same error:

```
Unreadable Notebook: C:\Users\HP PC\Downloads\Task- 3 Compare prices..ipynb 
NotJSONError('Notebook does not appear to be JSON: \'{ "cells": "[\\n\\n 
{\\n\\n "cell_type":...',
```

How can I get my .ipynb fiel from this?

Comment: You may have got rid of the line numbers but not the newlines. This is going to be a laborious fix

Comment: I'm not even sure `ast.literal_eval` is going to cope with this. How was this file created?

Comment: In the error message it says `"cells": "[`, note the quotation mark before the opening bracket. In the JSON part you have shown above it is `"cells": [`. Which one you have in the file after all?

Comment: Why are you even doing this btw? Isn't the file in the correct format to be read directly by the software, rather than somehow parsed out of JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the value of your field `.ipynb` without converting your file to json format.
by searching the value of your field directly in the `.txt` file.
it's not very convenient but it can be useful if it's the only value you need to extract from this file.

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if ".ipynb" in line: 
            print(line)
```

In the snippet above I just printed the line, assuming the value of your filed is in the same line with the key `.ipynb`, If it's the case you can replace the print something like:

```
ipnb_value = line.split(':')[1].strip()
```

I think it would be more helpful if you post the whole `.txt` file contents. 
I hope this helps!